# How to generate 5 columns random data with a specified correlation coefficient

Tags: r, correlation, simulation

I want to generate 5 columns with data **0 and 1**. I want to have a correlation coefficient of 0.70 between individual columns.

I understand we could do it with the **mvrnorm** function in the MASS package as explained already [Generate two variables with precise pre-specified correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83172/generate-two-variables-with-precise-pre-specified-correlation)

But this does not generate data between 0 and 1. I wonder if I have missed something.  It is very good to demonstrate it using R codes.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could advise me for downvoting? I am searching and working hard to find out a solution, but unsuccessful. Your help very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the reason for the downvote. Do you want correlated vectors of purely $0$'s & $1$'s, or do you want continuous values (w/ some distribution) that fall in the interval $(0,1)$?

Comment: Many thanks for your message, @gung-Reinstate Monica. I want only 'purely 0's and 1's".

Comment: Do you have a specified base rate?  It will be easiest if you have ~50% 1's, but can be possible w/ other base rates.  How many values do you want?  Again, it gets harder w/ fewer rows.

Comment: Yes, 50% is great. I want to have a sample size of 200